# rxjs5 get last emitted value upon subscription

Tags: rxjs5

Using rxjs 5, I want to subscribe to an observable and begin the stream with the last emitted value. The operator '.cache' is supposed to be built for this (I think) but I can't get it to work. I did a small test where fire an observable (by clicking a button) then subscribe to it 3 seconds later. In theory, I should get that click emission upon subscription, but I don't.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/commit/4308a04

http://codepen.io/BradLee/pen/VaqreL

```
let btn = document.querySelector(`btn`),
    btn$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(btn, `click`)
             .cache(1);

setTimeout(() => { 
    btn$.subscribe(evt => console.log('fired') );
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to RxJS. Your query selector is incorrect, if you change:

```
let btn = document.querySelector(`btn`),
```

to

```
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
```

It works.

**edit**

Until there is at least one subscription with `cache` it won't emit any events.
If you need to receive events from before the `subscribe` occurs you either need to create an immediate subscription so that you can start receiving events.

```
let btn = document.querySelector(`btn`),
    btn$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(btn, `click`)
             .cache(1);

btn$.subscribe();
```

Or you need to use the `publishReplay` operator and connect with it instead:

```
let btn = document.querySelector(`btn`),
    btn$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(btn, `click`)
             .publishReplay(1);

btn$.connect();
```

Comment: that was a problem but it doesn't solve the rxjs problem. If you click the button before the 3 second timer fires you should get a console msg when the timer fires, but you don't.

Comment: That is expected behavior. You haven't subscribed to the `Observable` yet so it can't receive any events yet. I edited with a solution for that as well.